# How can you stop react-native-marketingcloudsdk from auto enroling contacts into push

Tags: react-native, react-native-marketingcloudsdk

When setting up sfmcsdk on react-native, I can't find a way to stop the app from enabling push by default. This is reproduced in [this repo](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/react-native-marketingcloudsdk/tree/master), credentials not added as they are private.

Have I missed a builder method I can use to disable this, or do I have to disable push when the contact opens the app for the first time?

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior of the SDK is to enable Push. We have a way to disable push once the SDK is initialized using https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/appledocs/MarketingCloudSdk/7.6/Classes/MarketingCloudSDK.html#/c:objc(cs)MarketingCloudSDK(im)sfmc_setPushEnabled:

We do not have a builder method in the initial configuration to enable/disable push in the SDK.

Hope this answers your query.

Thanks,
Prakashini